# signed urls Amazon S3, what should be the min expiration time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, pre-signed-url

if i set say 1 min expiration but due to large file if it can not be downloaded within expiry time, will download will break/cancelled as time expired.

i need to keep the mim expiration time due to some reason.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expiration time is only tested when S3 initially receives the request.

The amount of time the download requires is not important, because the "expiration" time refers to how long the signed url can be used to *begin* downloading.

The exception to this is not really an exception, though it might appear to be if you didn't understanf what was happening.  HTTP and S3 allow a client to specify a range of bytes to download. It is probably not common, but it is possible, for a download to be done in discrete chunks.  If the client is attempting this, then all of the pieces have to be requested before the signed url expires, since the time each request is made is validated against the expiration time of the signed url.